# Rest/spread parameter type

Tags: typescript

For this piece of code:

```
type Callback = (err: Error | null, result: String) => void;

let apiThatAcceptsCallback = (cb: Callback) => { /*...*/ }; 

function callback(err: Error | null, result: String) {}


apiThatAcceptsCallback((...args) => {
    console.log(args);
    callback(...args);
});
```

`callback(...args)` causes an error:

> Expected 2 arguments, but got 0 or more.

How can this issue be addressed in type-safe manner? Falling back to `callback.apply(null, args)` in ES6 feels wrong.

Note that there could be not 2 arguments but 10 of them, so enumerating them is not a good choice.

Comment: Yeah, typescript can't really check that since ...args  can have any number of elements, and so I guess forbids it ..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Couldn't even find any reasonable workaround here, TS ignores `args` type assertions, the closest I came up was `(callback as (...args) => void)(...args)`. If you have better ideas, please, feel free to share.

Comment: This https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897, might be the closest we will get for now, but not until 3.0. Don't have any better ideas ..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thanks for the reference, couldn't find this one, looks very promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, all you can get is yucky workarounds that are not type safe.  Starting in TypeScript 3.0, which should come out [quite soon (July 2018)](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#30-july-2018), you will be able to use [tuples in rest/spread positions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897).  If you want to try it now you can use [`typescript@next`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Nightly-drops).

Once that lands you will be able to do:

```
// turn a function's parameters into a tuple, might be in standard library
type Parameters<T extends Function> = T extends (...args: infer U) => any ? U : any[];

apiThatAcceptsCallback((...args: Parameters<Callback>) => {
  console.log(args);
  callback(...args); // no error
});
```

In that code you need to explicitly type `...args` as `Parameters<Callback>` since it doesn't seem to get inferred from context (I wonder if that should be a feature request), but you don't have to enumerate anything since `Parameters<Callback>` is exactly the type you want to use.

Hope that (eventually) helps.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, hope the answer will be applicable soon.